# C++ compile error, "malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c++, pointers

```
using namespace std;

struct data{

    int id;
    char name[50];
    double fare;
    bool connecting;
    int priority;

};

struct node{

    data info;
    node* Next;
    node* Prev;

    node(const int i, const char *n, const double f, const bool c, const int p){

        info.id = i;
        strcpy(info.name,n);
        info.fare = f;
        info.connecting = c;
        info.priority = p;
        Next = NULL;
        Prev = NULL;
    }
};

class AirlineQueue{

    private:

        node* head;
        node* prev;
        node* next;

    public:


        AirlineQueue(){

            prev = NULL;
            next = NULL;
        }

        void addCustomer(node*);
        node* delCustomer();     
};

void AirlineQueue::addCustomer(node* n){

    if(prev == NULL){

        prev = n;
        next = n;

    }
    else {
             node* tmp = prev;

             if(n->info.id > tmp->info.id){

                 prev->Prev = n;
                 n->Next = prev;
                 prev = n;
             }
             else{

                  while (n->info.id < tmp->info.id)
                  {
                      if(tmp->Next == NULL)
                          break;
                      tmp = tmp->Next;            
                  }

                  if(tmp->Next == NULL && n->info.id < tmp->info.id){                  
                      next->Next = n;
                      n->Prev = next;
                      next = n;
                  }
                  else{         
                        tmp->Prev->Next = n;
                        n->Prev = tmp->Prev;
                        n->Next = tmp;
                        tmp->Prev = n;
                      }
        }
    }
}

node* AirlineQueue::delCustomer(){

    node* tmp;
    if(next == NULL)
        return NULL;

    else if(next->Prev == NULL){

             node* tmp2 = next;
             tmp = tmp2;
             prev = NULL;
             next = NULL;
             delete tmp2;
             return tmp;
         }
         else{
               node* tmp2 = next;
               tmp = tmp2;
               next = next->Prev;
               next->Next = NULL;
               delete tmp2;
               return tmp;
             }
}

void printQueue(node* h){

    if(h == NULL){

        std::cout << "No customer is in the queue at this moment. " ;

    }
    else{

          cout << "The customer ID is      " << h->info.id;
          cout << "The customer's name is  " << h->info.name;
          cout << "The ticket fare is      " << h->info.fare;
          cout << "The priority of the customer is " << h->info.priority;
          cout << "Whether the customer is connecting with the flight " << h->info.connecting;

      }
}


int main(){

    AirlineQueue * queue = new AirlineQueue();

    node No1(100, "Alice", 1500.5,  1, 1);
    node No2(101, "Bill",  1300.15, 0, 3);
    node No3(103, "Claire",1100.45, 1, 4);
    node No4(104, "Dylan", 1100.45, 0, 5);
    node No5(105, "Ellen", 1100.45, 1, 2);
    node No6(106, "Faye",  1100.45, 0, 7);
    node No7(107, "Garry", 1100.45, 1, 3);
    node No8(108, "Hellen",1100.45, 1, 6);
    node No9(109, "Ilene", 1100.45, 0, 5);
    node No10(110,"Jenny", 1100.45, 0, 7);

    queue->addCustomer(&No10);
    queue->addCustomer(&No3);
    queue->addCustomer(&No5);
    queue->addCustomer(&No7);
    queue->addCustomer(&No1);
    queue->addCustomer(&No9);
    queue->addCustomer(&No8);
    queue->addCustomer(&No6);
    queue->addCustomer(&No4);
    queue->addCustomer(&No2);

    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());
    printQueue(queue->delCustomer());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is a little confusing because you don't call `malloc` or `free` anywhere. Just know that `delete` calls `free` and `new` calls `malloc` (on most platforms). So basically, this error (probably not a compile error, but if it is, then kudos to your compiler for doing the static analysis) says that you are calling `delete` on a pointer that was not obtained via `new`.

Comment: Dear Justin, Thanks for your input. However, I don't follow, could you please explain more details about the error?

Comment: As it is, your question isn't fit for stackoverflow. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically, go through your code and remove things until the error goes away. Try to remove as much as possible. Please do this on a copy of the code, however, not the actual code itself. If you do this, you might even find the problem yourself. Additionally, the question should be in the question body itself, not just the title (and the error message too)

Comment: Sorry for my bad. Really appreciate your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You pass to the `addCustomer` method pointer to the `node` object with the automatic storage duration:

```
node No10(110,"Jenny", 1100.45, 0, 7);
queue->addCustomer(&No10);
```

Yet `delCustomer` uses `delete` operator. Since memory was not dynamically allocated, attempting to free its is an undefined behavior:

> In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of
>   delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object
>   created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject
>   ([intro.object]) representing a base class of such an object (Clause
>   [class.derived]). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be
>   a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous
>   array new-expression.82 If not, the behavior is undefined.

Best approach would be to avoid direct memory management and use a smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead.